# If I have an array of strings (which include symbols) how can I strip out the elements whose symbols make up non-words?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an array that looks like this:

```
> uniq_words
=> ["Welcome",
 "Occurred",
 "John (CPA)",
 "{",
 "if(",
 ")",
 "//",
 "target",
 "=",
 "}",
 "else",
 "target.style.display",
 "The",
 "web",
 "site"]
```

As you can see, there are some elements of this array that are bits of code and have `{` and `(`.

This is where it gets tricky though, what I would like to do is strip out the elements that are obviously non words -- so things like `=`, `}`, `if(` and `)` should be stripped out (or any other symbols like `*&^%$` etc.).

But the key is the context.

`John (CPA)` should not be stripped, neither should `Mr. Smith` or `Johnson & Johnson`, etc.

So how do I cleanse `uniq_words` of those elements? I imagine I would likely use `.select` and some regex, but how would all of the pieces look together?

**Edit 1**

Per Cary's comment, what I am essentially trying to do is search through all the text on a website for names. However, some names may include titles beside them (like `John Brown (MBA)`). So I don't want any string that is obviously not a word, and almost certainly not a name. Spaces are a must for obvious reasons.

I don't need the regex to fully match names, because I know that's almost impossible, I just don't want it to allow obviously non words (e.g. `//` or `=` or `(`, without excluding valid strings like `John Brown (Esq.)`).

I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: You have given examples of strings to keep and strings to ditch, but that's not enough. You need to provide precise criteria for the inclusion or exclusion of a string. Without that we'd just be guessing. I suspect it would be easier to provide criteria for strings to keep. For example, do want to strings comprised entirely of word characters and spaces, or perhaps just letters and spaces, but also permit strings of letters enclosed in parens (and braces? and brackets?), etc.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I updated the question to answer your comment.

Comment: This is impossible unless the AI is robust enough and smarter than me, since I myself doubt what should be left and what should be ignored. My first guess would be your parser, you use to break the text into parts is broken. Spaces in `"John (CPA)"` look too suspicious. In any case you are to use [`Enumerable#grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep).

Comment: Pulling out names such as "Dr. J. Paul O'Connor-Smith III, MD" is going to be tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your clarification, the best I came up with would be:

```
input.grep(/\A[\p{Alnum}\s]+(\([\p{Alnum}\s]+\))?\z/)
#⇒ [
#  [0] "Welcome",
#  [1] "Occurred",
#  [2] "John (CPA)",
#  [3] "target",
#  [4] "else",
#  [5] "The",
#  [6] "web",
#  [7] "site"
# ]
```

Remove the trailing question mark to search for names *with titles only*:

```
input.grep(/\A[\p{Alnum}\s]+(\([\p{Alnum}\s]+\))\z/)
#⇒ ["John (CPA)"]
```

The regulars are using [proper unicode character classes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) to match names like “Köhl” and/or “Liña.”

Comment: Can you explain this a bit please. What's the `Alnum` do?

Comment: Added a clarification.

Comment: You chose `\p{Alnum}` over `\p{Alpha}` so you wouldn't miss people like  *007*?

Comment: @CarySwoveland exactly. Also, n00bs should be honored too.